# How to say to the derived class which protected base class member to use

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, protected

Consider the example below:

```cpp
class Base {
protected:
    struct SubStruct { double value; };
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        data.value = 3.14;
    }
    Base::SubStruct data;
};


int main()
{
    Derived instance;
    std::cout << instance.data.value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `Derived` class has the `data` member of the type that is defined in its base class. Pay special attention to that the `SubStruct` type is protected in `Base`.

Now I'm enhancing the `Base` with a choice of substructs. To select which substruct to use I'm making the `Derived` template:

```cpp
class Base {
protected:
    struct SubStructInt { int value; };
    struct SubStructDouble { double value; };
};

template<typename S>
struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {
        data.value = 3.14;
    }
    S data;
};


int main()
{
    Derived<Base::SubStructInt> instanceInt;
    std::cout << instanceInt.data.value << std::endl;
    Derived<Base::SubStructDouble> instanceDouble;
    std::cout << instanceDouble.data.value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That doesn't compile because the substructs are protected, and I cannot instantiate the `Derived` with the types protected in `Base` (everything works if I make them public).

I don't want to make the substructs public, so I found a solution with `std::conditional`:

```cpp
template<bool flag>
struct Derived : public Base {
    using SubStruct = std::conditional_t<flag, SubStructInt, SubStructDouble>;

    Derived() {
        data.value = 3.14;
    }
    SubStruct data;
};
```

Anyway, I think that this is not the best/idiomatic solution to the problem: "how to say to the derived class which protected type of the base class to use". At the end of the day the protected subtypes are visible within Derived, and can be aliased from there:

```cpp
template<typename S>
struct Derived : public Base {
    using DerivedInt = Derived<SubStructInt>;
    using DerivedDouble = Derived<SubStructDouble>;

    // ...    
};
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you are imposing conflicting requirements. On one hand, you want the nested `struct`s of `Base` to be `protected`. On the other hand, you want the users of `Derived` to know about them and use them. You may want to rethink your requirements and constraints.

Comment: The fact that I'm making `data` public is irrelevant. In my design the `Base` provides multiple possible implementations for the derived classes. I can define separate classes `Derived1` and `Derived2` for different implementations, but that would duplicate the code. I'm trying to make a `template<> Derived` instead.

Comment: `data` is a `public` member but that's not what I am talking about. You want client code to be able to use `Derived<Base::SubStructInt>`. That's what I am talking about.

Comment: To be precise, I want to use `struct Derived<__something__>:Base { private: Base::SubStruct s; };`, where `Base::SubStruct` is visible by `Derived`, and `__something__` is a client's choice. And that repeats the solution with `std::conditional`.

Comment: In that case, you expect the client to know that `__something__` maps to `Base::SubStruct_1` and `__anotherthing__` maps to `Base::SubStruct_2`. Correct?

Comment: Correct. But that is not private but protected, and is exposed for extension. I'm using the protected member exactly for that. I'm not arguing for the syntax (which is wrong), but my intension is: "Use SubStruct for extension of the Derived, and give me the possible extended Derived classes".